# Evo Pdf not converting HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, evopdf

Evo PDF not converting HTML to PDF which contains more than 1000 pages including 2000 images.

```
 pdfConverter.NavigationTimeout = 5000;             
 pdfConverter.ConversionDelay = 300;
```

Comment: Do you have some more information about the error ? Exception or does the operation take extra long ?

Comment: @rboe no errors occuring but pdf contains partial data

Comment: better to use ratotiva

Answer (score 0):

Are you using with the latest version of the software? If not the you should try the latest version first.

How long does it take to completely load the HTML page in a browser on the same server on which you run the converter? Use CTRL-R to refresh the page in browser and make sure it doesn't load the cached images.

Did you try to increase the ConversionDelay and the NavigationTimeout? Do you have an URL of such a HTML page you are trying to convert?

Please contact EVO support if you need more help to solve this issue.